# Laravel 5.2 swiftmailer error

Tags: laravel, email, mailgun

I keep getting this error, despite trying all I could in the `.env` file. I even hardcoded the values in the `config/mail` file (removed them from the `.env` file), and it still gave the same error. I'm using a sandbox domain, with verified email addresses. The sandbox is active, and so are the email addresses.

```
PHP warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.mailgun.org:587 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
) in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelproject\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 267
Swift_TransportException with message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailgun.org [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 #10061]'
```

Comment: Is your antivirus blocking the request perhaps. Can you telnet to the port from a cmd prompt. telnet smtp.mailgun.org 587

Comment: @LeonVismer, it says could not open connection to the host, on port 587: connect failed

Comment: I presume other port 80, 25 traffic is going through? Then you either have a firewall or an antivirus packages that is blocking that port.